# How do I add an index, reusing some columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing

For example, let's take the query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE parent_id = 1
AND created > '2016-05-06 00:00:00'
ORDER BY updated DESC, created ASC
```

Wouldn't adding the following index be the best, to avoid using any file sorting?:

```
ADD INDEX `search` (`parent_id` ASC, `created` ASC, `updated` DESC, `created` ASC)
```

When trying to add the index, I get "Duplicate column". Is there any way to avoid this? I'm currently working with a rather large dataset, so optimization is key.

Comment: You don't need a duplicate `created` column.

Comment: That duplicated `created` should prevent the file sort that's happening.

Comment: That does not prevent the sort; mixing DESC and ASC prevents the use of an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX(parent_id, created)` is the best index for that query.  The columns must be in that order (`= constant` first, then 'range').  Adding on the other columns will not help.

Because you are mixing `DESC` and `ASC` in the `ORDER BY` (and because you cannot declare an index to be `DESC`), it is impossible to use an index to avoid the `ORDER BY`.

[More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 1):

You have the `created` column specified twice in your index's definition. Just get rid of the second one, and you should be OK:

```
ADD INDEX `search` (`parent_id` ASC, `created` ASC, `updated` DESC)
-- The second "created ASC" was removed here ---------------------^
```

Comment: I'm aware of what the issue is. The question is more philosophy. How do I achieve the best index for that query.

Comment: OK, yes.  But `updated` will not be looked at in the index.  Therefore is is wasting space.  It won't be looked at because `created` is used in a "range".

Answer (score 0):

You won't need two different indexes for querying and sorting. Same working in both operations So, just remove duplicated `created` from you ADD INDEX query.

Comment: The order of the columns should matter though. If created isn't on the end (again), the mysql resorts to filesorting, which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Actually, I'm not working with MySQL indexes, but as I see there's a lot of limitations
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Furthermore, MySQL almost never uses two indexes for one `SELECT`.  The only case is with "index merge", not `ORDER BY`.